# Is there a way to make the "viewer type" in Eclipse TCP/IP Monitor stick to "XML"?

Tags: eclipse

The "Request viewer type" and "Response viewer type" in Eclipse's TCP/IP Monitor always default to "Byte" for every request/response pair.

I prefer "XML", but that setting is not "sticky" between each request/response - i.e., I set it to XML before starting a session, or after, it doesn't matter, for each pair it goes back to "Byte".

I've googled this and I searched the preferences and I can't find anything that helps.